# Do I have enough data to build this model?

Tags: multilevel-analysis, intervention-analysis

My aim is to measure the effect of an intervention (policy change) on a dependent variable that was recorded yearly (see https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3415557/).

The same policy change took place in 4 different countries at 4 different points in time, therefore, time before and after the intervention varies from country to country. As there is only limited data for each country overall (20 to 30 data points), my plan is to pool the data and conduct an analysis through generalized linear mix modeling.

My main interest is the policy change effect for each country and an overall policy change effect.

My model should include the following:

- Random intercepts
- Random effects of time (as I am looking at measures over time, I want to adjust for possible time trends in the data)
- Random effect of the policy change

However, pooling the data I only have about 105 data points available.

My questions are:
- Do I have enough data points to accommodate the complexity of my model?
- If no, what **can** be done with the data available? How could I reduce complexity to make this analysis possible and still gain valuable insights?

Comment: As a colleague said: strong effects will always show. Personally, I would use bootstrapping and/or Bayesian approaches to evaluate the robustness of the analysis, but I would definitely try. In your model, I would state time x policy change as fixed effect, though, or as random slope for this interaction (maybe that is what you meant). Add an  AR1 for potential temporal autocorrelation, and indeed you have quite a few parameters to fit. FWIW: don't reduced model complexity if you think this is how it is; rather live with large uncertainty.

Comment: @Carsten - Thanks for these good insights.  Worth expanding into an Answer.

Comment: @Carsten Thank you for your reply! I read about a rule of thumb stating "random effects can only be specified practically for grouping factors which have at least five or six different levels". Will the fact that I only have four countries affect the quality of my outcome? Or, i.e., will I be able to draw meaningful conclusions from the analysis?

Comment: @lisannceline - There are plenty such rules of thumb, some with more, some with less support from simulations. I learned the "7 or more" levels as well. Based on unpublished simulations by a colleague, I don't think so anymore. Even 2 levels, preferably with a few replicates each, seem to be fine. But don't take my word for it, try to simulate such data and see for yourself.

Comment: @Carsten thank you very much for your insights!

Comment: @Carsten I tried to build a model using nlme (as lme4 doesn't allow to add an AR(1) process), however, the full model does not converge: ‘nlminb problem, convergence error code = 1 message = iteration limit reached without convergence (10)‘, even after increasing the maximum number of iterations. Does this say anything about the feasibility of the analysis?

Comment: @lisannceline: Sorry, can't help you there. I don't remember why nlminb problems arise here. Whenever this happens to me, I move to brms and hope that Bayes with long enough chains sorts it out. I think it has less to do with too few data as such and more with too strong correlation among the parameters (which of course is a too few data problem, too).